# Modificar la configuración de correo masivo dinámicamente en Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, email, swift-mailer

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en Laravel que cuenta con un conjunto de departamentos. Dependiendo del departamento, necesito utilizar una cuenta de correo u otra para enviar los mensajes de correo masivo.

Tengo una tabla donde guardo las diferentes cuentas de correo que registren los usuarios.

```
$email_account = EmailAccount::find($id);
```

Cuando se envían un correo a todos los clientes, utilizo:

```
Mail::to()->queue(new MassiveMail($email_account, $data));
```

El problema se origina cuando se intenta procesar la cola, Muestra el siguiente error:

```
[2019-05-16 19:16:47] local.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "example@mail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

Si en cambio utilizo:

```
Mail::to()->send(new MassiveMail($email_account, $data));
```

Los correos se envían!

Creo que el problema es que no logro que el procesamiento de la cola detecte la cuando te correo que le estoy enviando.

Alguien puede ayudarme?

**Actualización 19/05/2019**

Archivo .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.example.com
MAIL_PORT=xxx
MAIL_USERNAME=example@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=xxx
```

Archivo config/mail.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

Archivo config/queue.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel's queue API supports an assortment of back-ends via a single
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for every one. Here you may define a default connection.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('SQS_KEY', 'your-public-key'),
            'secret' => env('SQS_SECRET', 'your-secret-key'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'region' => env('SQS_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

Comment: tiene corriendo el queue worker? `php artisan queue:work`

Comment: sí, está ejecutándose, he intentando con `php artisan queue:work` y con `php artisan queue:listen` pero en ambos casos el problema no se resuelve

Comment: podrías mostrar como lo tienes configurado en `.env` y en  `config/mail.php`? (sin mostrarnos username ni password obviamente)

Comment: Actualicé el pos con lo solicitado, aunque la idea no es obtener las credenciales desde ahí, requiero obtenerlas desde la base de datos.

Comment: Ok, creo que no me entendiste (`config/database.php` no afecta para enviar emails. Sí `MAIL_DRIVER, MAIL_HOST, MAIL_PORT, MAIL_ENCRYPTION` en el `.env` y lo que tengas en `config/mail.php` y tal vez `config/queue.php`). A lo que iba es a que no sabemos como es tu configuración para poder ayudarte. [Aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgHQNkxYzMI) hay un tutorial en español. Quizá te sirva. Hay muchos más que puedes encontrar si lo googleas.

Comment: Lo siento, ingresé el archivo equivocado. Ahora si, cargué mi configuración en los archivos mail.php y queue.php.